# What does this tensorflow message mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

So this is a Digit Recognizer made with ML..
So I'm getting this error and my program just quits after giving out this command.
Tried installing `tensorflow-cpu` and usual tensorflow aswell..

I have an AMD GPU, and a Core i5-10th Gen CPU

```
2021-11-16 18:53:54.873365: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

Also I've already saved the model and Here's the code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('handwritten.model')

image_number = 1

while os.path.isfile(f'Image\\Digits{image_number}.png'):
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(f'Image\\Digits{image_number}.png')[:,:,0]
        img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
        prediction = model.predict(img)
        speak(f"This Digit is Probably a {np.argmax(prediction)}")
        plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)

    except:
        speak("Error!")

    finally:
        image_number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is only compatible with Nvidia GPUs (using Cuda language). Concerning the message, it's only a warning telling you that you can better optimize Tensorflow on CPU by compiling it from the source code with the appropriate flags, in order to take into account the AVX AVX2 instruction sets of your CPU. This being said, you will only be able to train simple models for computation time reasons.

Comment: It's a warning, i know that, but the problem that arises is, It just closes my Application after showing that Error, which shouldn't happen

Comment: What OS are you working on?

Comment: Windows.. Windows 11